# How to reduce aggregration time mongo db

Tags: database, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have written this query to aggregate data

```
db.attendancesCollection.aggregate([
   {
      '$match': {
         'Date': { "$gte": start_date, "$lte": end_date },
         'Location': found_location["locationName"],
         'locationId': { '$exists': True },
         'workerType': workerType
      }
   },
   {
      "$group": {
         '_id': {
            'employeeId': '$employeeId',
            'workerId': '$workerId',
            'workerFullName': '$workerFullName'
         },
         'dailyPointsArray': {
            '$push': {
               'Date': '$Date',
               'createdAs': '$createdAs',
               'Points': '$shiftPoints',
               'inTime': '$inTime',
               'outTime': '$outTime',
            }
         },
         'total_shift_points': { '$sum': '$shiftPoints' },
         'total_duration': { '$sum': '$duration' },
      }
   },
   {
      '$addFields': {
         'Location': found_location["locationName"],
      }
   },
   {
      '$lookup':
         {
            'from': "users",
            'localField': "_id.employeeId",
            'foreignField': "_id",
            'as': "userInfo"
         }
   }
])
```

There is no issue in running this query, I am getting desired data, but the problem lies in the execution time of the query, it takes about 20-30 secs for that, there are about 500,000 documents in  attendance collection where I am performing aggregation & 1000 docs in user Collection where I am performing a lookup, what can I do to reduce execution time

This is sample structure

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60dd7d723fcb2eb7df248af3"
    },
    "workerId": "xxxx",
    "workerFullName": "ARUN",
    "workerType": "Employee",
    "workerAadharCardNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "Date": {
        "$date": "2021-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "employeeId": {
        "$oid": "60dd77c14524e6c116e1692c"
    },
    "Location": "HEAD OFFICE",
    "sourceUnitType": null,
    "duration": null,
    "shiftPoints": null,
    "createdAs": "ABSENT",
    "ruleApplied": null,
    "detections": [],
    "locationId": {
        "$oid": "60dd6d303da6c17209d5ef68"
    },
    "workerFaceRegistered": true
}
```

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: _id & Date are indexes

Comment: Then try to add index on Date, Location, workerType - depending on cardinality.